# How do I access the drag and drop position (i.e. line number of mouse) as indicated by this dotted marker in Monaco Editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using [react-dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) + [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/). I'm trying to implement a feature whereby users can drag and drop an image into the editor, which I then process and convert to a text reference (much like you can do on github).

Here's what this looks like

[image]

Notice how Monaco Editor exposes a marker the follows my mouse. **How do I get the line number / position of this marker, so I can programmatically insert text there on the drop event?**